# Customizing jfreechart

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart, stacked-chart

[image]

I have Figure 1 and I am using the following code for it:

```
ItemLabelPosition p = new ItemLabelPosition( 
ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE3, TextAnchor.TOP_RIGHT, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT, 0.0);
```

I want to get the chart as Figure 2 where the counts are shown at the junction of two stacked bars.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of chart are you using? What renderer?

Comment: I am using stacked bar chart. The renderer is of type GroupedStackedBar.